# How can i change so that my site only show price with tax

Tags: tax

Help, i am trying to get my T-shirt shop http://tex-tryk.dk/ to show frontend price with tax as the is now low in Denmark ?

Comment: have you tried googling [Magento display price with taxes](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=Magento+display+price+with+taxes) ?

Answer (score 3):

In your admin go to:

```
system > configuration > sales > tax > default tax destination calculation
```

Set this for Denmark

Go to:

```
system > configuration > sales > tax > price display settings (just below the previous tab)
```

Set "Display Product Prices In Catalog" to Including Tax

Save Config